# Story about a young man with photographic memory who becomes a space doctor

Tags: story-identification, childrens-novel

I probably read this book in the late 1960s in an elementary school library. I believe the story began with the young man on Earth and progressed to him having an adventure in space. His photographic memory was central to his character and probably the story also.

For years I thought the book may have been called something like *Space Doctor* or *Star Surgeon*. Books with those names exist but I have not found the one I am looking for. I may be in error about the name.

Comment: Can't find a summary, and I don't particularly remember it, but this 'feels' like a good possibility: "Doctor to the Galaxy" (1965) by A. M. Lightner. Looking for your book, I found a long-lost of my own, Lightner's "The Rock of Three Planets" (1963), so thank you! and good luck with your search.

Comment: Star Surgeon is part of [*Sector General*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sector_General) series. Photographic memory wasn't featured there.

Comment: FYI, I checked Alan E. Nourse as well - [Star Surgeon](http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/18492), close, but no 'memory' bit; Hubbard, White also had no good match.

Comment: The perfect memory main character is a feature of Heinlein's *Starman Jones*, but Jones became an astrogator, not a doctor.

Answer (score 5):

Could it be [*Sucker Bait*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sucker_Bait), a novella by Asimov?

In it, 20-year-old Mark Annuncio of the "Mnemonic Service", who has been trained to memorize and correlate vast amounts of information, saves the crew of a spaceship investigating a planet that turns out to have an abnormally high concentration of beryllium in its soil.

Answer (score 3):

Turning [a comment](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/49955/story-about-a-young-man-with-photographic-memory-who-becomes-a-space-doctor/49960#comment93958_49955) into a community answer, this might be *[Starman Jones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Starman_Jones)* by Robert A. Heinlein. It was published in 1953 as part of his juvenile series, which matches with when you read it and with it being a children's novel (going by the tag you used).

The protagonist is Max Jones, an orphaned farm boy who wants to go to space. His uncle may have left him astrogation manuals. He meets a hobo, Sam, who helps him, but also cheats him out of the manuals. Sam does get them jobs on a spaceship.
Max' eidetic memory allows him to memorise all the manuals, which helps them later (after he has become an astrogator) when the manuals are destroyed.

The covers can be found [on the ISFDb](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/titlecovers.cgi?1121) and may help jog your memory.